# Sublime Text Editor Anaconda package Autoformat PEP8 Errors doesn't automatically reformat comments that are too long

Tags: comments, sublimetext, pep8, sublime-text-plugin, sublime-anaconda

I'm trying the STE Anaconda's autoformatting feature and it works well with every other PEP8 feature but seems to not change any lines that are like:

```
def foo():  # asasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasas
    pass
```

even though the line is clearly longer than the PEP8 limit. Is there a setting that I'm missing or does Anaconda not cover this with it's autoformatter? Are there any other PEP8 formatting packages / comment wrapping packages that anyone recommends?

Alternatively, are comments exempt from this 79 character limit by any chance?

Comment: From the [Maximum Line Length](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id19) section of PEP8: *Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters. For flowing long blocks of text with fewer structural restrictions (docstrings or comments), the line length should be limited to 72 characters.* So, looks like comments are not exempt.